# Python/Supervisord gives AttributeError: module 'typing' has no attribute 'Literal'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydev

I am running a python application using supervisord in a docker container.  When starting the application, I am getting below error:

```
*** Operational MODE: preforking+threaded ***
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./main.py", line 11, in <module>
    from flask_log_request_id.extras.celery import enable_request_id_propagation
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/flask_log_request_id/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .request_id import RequestID, current_request_id
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/flask_log_request_id/request_id.py", line 4, in <module>
    from flask import request, g, current_app
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import json as json
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/flask/json/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from ..globals import current_app
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/flask/globals.py", line 6, in <module>
    from werkzeug.local import LocalProxy
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/werkzeug/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .serving import run_simple as run_simple
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 76, in <module>
    t.Union["ssl.SSLContext", t.Tuple[str, t.Optional[str]], t.Literal["adhoc"]]
AttributeError: module 'typing' has no attribute 'Literal'
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. GAME OVER ***
```

Comment: [`typing.Literal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Literal) was _"New in version 3.8."_, so given you're using 3.9 that shouldn't be happening. Is `typing` definitely the standard library module?

Comment: Try `import typing; print(typing.__file__)`

Comment: root@78330c48fb95:/app# python3

Python 3.9.2 (default, Feb 28 2021, 17:03:44)
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import typing; print(typing.__file__)
/usr/lib/python3.9/typing.py